# HOw to trace data reads of a process

Tags: c#

Hello I am trying to count the number of data reads and writes called by a process.Is this possible using C#.net.Can anyone help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "data read"?

Comment: i mean a read or write call issued by a process.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the performance counters to monitor the IO Read Bytes/sec and IO Write Bytes/sec counters and accumulate the values each second to have a rough idea of the total number of bytes.

Comment: Can u please help me with namespace and methods that can achieve this.iam a newbie and struggling to find methods in c#.

Comment: You can use System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter. Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MonitoringProcess.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can also add event handlers for WMI events:

[Receiving WMI event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#event_queries)